# Low media sound volume on huawei nova 3e

Tags: huawei, volume-control, volume

The volume is to the max but is a bit quiet. Is there a way to increase it without installing apps? Android 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try testing your phone speakers first and play some high dB audio... You can also try testing by using speaker phone during a call.

There are several cases that it is a damaged speaker or loosed contact on speaker.